# Pre_Replace Keep Caps

Tags: php, regex

Basically I'm just wondering if there is an easy way to detect whether or not a string is all-caps, and then make the thing replacing it either caps or not caps accordingly.

Example:

```
 $str = "WELL HI THERE BOB!";
 $str = preg_replace("hi", "greetings", $str);
```

That would come out "WELL greetings THERE BOB", but I want it to come out "WELL GREETINGS THERE BOB".

And I would want:

```
 $str = "Well hi there bob";
 $str = preg_replace("hi", "greetings", $str);
```

To come out: "Well greetings there bob!"

So, again, I want it to keep it all caps, but only if it is already all-capsed.

Comment: Your `preg_replace` will generate warning. I _guess_ you used `i` identifier in your actual code?

Comment: Yeah, I know that isn't correct syntax. I kept it simple just to set an example of what I was looking for.

Comment: That's a little too "simple". Remove `i` identifier in your actual code may help you: `preg_replace('#hi#i','greeting',$str)` will replace `HI`, but `preg_replace('#hi#','greeting',$str)` will not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this with just regex search/replace.  If you only need to worry about individual words you could use:

```
str_replace(array("hi", "HI"), array("goodbye", "GOODBYE"), $str);
```

Depending on your exact needs you can use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) so you can get the exact match and check the case of individual letters of the matched value and return the replacement based on that.

Comment: The way my real code is laid out, this was the best solution. I had no idea you could use arrays in str_replace like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ctype_upper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-upper.php) function to determine whether a string is all uppercase:

```
$str = "WELL HI THERE BOB!";
$replace = "greetings";

$replace = ctype_upper($str) ? strtoupper($str) : strtolower($replace);
$str = str_replace("hi", $replace, $str);
```

I've used a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to test whether `$str` is in uppercase. If so, `$replace` is converted to uppercase. If not, it's converted to lowercase.

#### Output

> `$str = "WELL GREETINGS THERE BOB!";`

Comment: I like this solution, thank you for the time you used to provide it and I may use it for something else some day. I did however end up using the other answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $str = "WELL HI THERE BOB!";  
 $str = str_replace('hi', 'greetings', $str);
 $str = str_replace('HI', 'GREETINGS', $str);
    if (!(strtoupper($str) == $str)) {      
    $str = ucfirst(strtolower($str)); 
  } else{
    $str = strtoupper($str);      
  }
 echo $str; 
 ?>
```

**Output:**

When input is : `$str = "WELL HI THERE BOB!"`

`WELL GREETINGS THERE BOB!`

and When Input is  `$str = "WELL hi THERE BOB!";`

```
Well greetings there bob!
```